# Alternative of Tableau

Tags: tableau-crm

If we want to Visually represent Event Monitoring Data, do we have any alternative other than Tableau. Also is there any tool that is free.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to use Tableau nor Tableau CRM (they're distinctly different tools despite the name) to visualize Event Monitoring Data. A benefit of Tableau (*Server* or *Online*) is that it integrates easily with Salesforce (it is a Salesforce product) should you want to use that for visualizations and then Tableau CRM is convenient in that you can work with the data and the dashboards all from within Salesforce.

The Event Monitoring Data is stored as [`EventLogFile`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) data in your org. That data can be [downloaded using the REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_event_log_file_download.htm) or using [Event Log File Browser in your internet browser](https://salesforce-elf.herokuapp.com/) and then analyzed using any analytics tool you desire. In terms of free tools, the only one that I'm aware of is Apache Superset (*free, open-sourced, Apache 2.0 license*) but take a look around for what's out there.